# call value objects from other files into an object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, call

i have message object that contain :

```
const message = {
        headers: {
            i need to call another object to here
        }
};
```

and i have config object in another file :

```
exports.custom_headers{

    'x-my-key': 'header value',
    'x-another-key': 'another value'

}
```

i need to replace whole name and value of headers: with the object from config file

how to reference that ? 
I tried calling objects directly but it didn't work

normaly the object work like this

```
const message = {
    from: random_message.fromname+'<'+random_message.fromemail+'>',
    to: email,
    subject: random_message.subject,
    text: random_message.text,
    html: random_message.html,
    headers: {
            'x-my-key': 'header value',
            'x-another-key': 'another value'
    }
};
```

but i need to export headers to another file

Comment: Your message object is invalid Javascript.

Comment: no it is an object in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you want. You can use `...` (spread operator) to spread the keys of the object.

```js
const custom_headers =  {
    'x-my-key': 'header value',
    'x-another-key': 'another value'
};

const message = {
   from: 'random_message.fromname'+'<'+'random_message.fromemail'+'>',
   to: 'email',
   subject: 'random_message.subject',
   text: 'random_message.text',
   html: 'random_message.html',
  headers:{
    ...custom_headers
  }
};

console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//basically you have 2 object and wants to override one object's with another

//here is one object
const message = {
        headers: {
            "old-header1": "old-header-value1",
        "common-property": "old-header-value2"
        }
};

//here is config object
const config = {
    "new-header1": "new-header-value1",

    "common-property": "new-header-value2"
};

//message.headers = {}; //uncomment this if you want to remove all older properties

//to override properties
Object.keys(config).forEach(function(d) { message.headers[d] = config[d]; });
```